# Añadir campos TableView Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

actualmente estoy probando las propiedades del tableview para crear un menú de opciones. Sin embargo, he logrado incluir solo un campo para cambiar una pantalla. Mi proposito es crear 4 celdas para cambiar a diferentes pantallas.
Actualmente dispongo del siguiente codigo paa cumplir el objetivo, muchas gracias por el aporte que me puedan brindar.

Anexo que si cambio el return 1 por los 4 que me hacen falta estos se repiten en cada tabla y claramente no es la idea. Saludos!

```
import UIKit
protocol SlideMenuDelegate {
func slideMenuItemSelectedAtIndex(_ index: Int32)
 }

 class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewCell") as! MenuTableViewCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainStoreboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Menu", bundle: nil)
    let DVC = mainStoreboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScheduleViewController") as!
    ScheduleViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Qué significa la etiqueta *"rápido"* en la pregunta? Todas tus preguntas la tienen.

Comment: Hola amigo, cuando etiqueto las preguntas con ios xcode y swift se autotraduce  swift con rapido u.u

Comment: Deberías considerar colocar el tag correcto. El sitio si permite colocar etiquetas en inglés.

Comment: Ya amigo, gracias por la observación.